# Do vacuum bubbles exist in theories with normal ordered Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

When we calculate the Hamiltonian in the free theory, we notice that it contains an infinitely large term 
\begin{align} 
H  
&=  \int_V \mathrm{d }k^3  \frac{\omega_k}{(2\pi)^3 }   a^\dagger(\vec k) a(\vec k)+ \frac{1}{2} \int_V \mathrm{d }k^3  \omega_k  \delta(\vec 0)   
\, .
\end{align}
We can get rid of this term by claiming that nature only uses normal ordered operators, in which case there is no infinitely large term.

As soon as add an interaction term like $\phi^4$, we encounter the same problem. If we switch the operators around using the commutation relations we find infinitely large terms that are all related to field commutators evaluated at the same spacetime point $[\phi_{-}(x) ,\phi_{+}(x)]  \sim \infty $. In diagrammatic form, these terms are given by self-loop diagrams

[image]

Again, the problem can be solved by demanding that the Hamiltonian is brought into normal form before we quantize it. If we work with a normal ordered Hamiltonian there are no self-loop diagrams.

This seems to suggest that if we work with normal ordered Hamiltonians, at least some of the vacuum bubble diagrams no longer exist. Does normal ordering remove all vacuum bubble diagrams or are there some remnant diagrams that are not removed through the process of normal ordering?

[image]

Comment: To what extent normal ordering can cure divergent integrals? Take a look at this book: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=LzT6CAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=salmhofer+renormalization&ots=aU9q5bd7tG&sig=IKRByXAk_yffrjkicGlP0vQ26gs#v=onepage&q=salmhofer%20renormalization&f=false

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, that's a little strange to unilaterally mark this question as a duplicate with a question that is only tangentially related. I saw that you happened to give a long answer that touched on this issue. But might it not be a little better to simply link to your answer in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all the vacuum bubbles are removed by normal ordering. Your third diagram at the end of your post is an example.

Comment: Second nether, due to the sandwiched bubble.

Comment: @MadMax, the second diagram will not contribute because of the two loops which aren't sandwiched

Comment: yes, you are right.